# Is there any way to know current url is in a specific blueprint in flask?

Tags: python, url, flask, jinja2

in my flask app I can use a blueprint to register lots of routes..

```
@myblueprint.route('/first')
@myblueprint.route('/two')
@myblueprint.route('/three')
```

my problem is that I need to know current url in in a specific blueprint.so I can give it a `class='active'` css effect in jinja template?
So is there any way I can do using flask 0.10.0?

Comment: Don't you have a prefix for your blueprint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`request.blueprint`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.blueprint) will be the current blueprint name if the request is being handled by a blueprint.